# Mocking timers when unit testing a communication library with timeouts

Tags: .net, unit-testing, time, timeout

I have to maintain a rather big library implementing a communication protocol with different layers. Fortunately, there are thousands of unit tests for many different situations.

I have problems with those unit tests probing for timeouts within the library. The timeouts are in the range of a few seconds which is unacceptably long for unit-testing.

What we already did is to implement a single central clock service which can be configured to run faster by a certain factor. By this, the tests complete much faster. But we cannot choose this factor too large, as then some tests begin to fail randomly because the performance of the test machine varies. Also, it is a nightmare to debug.

I feel that it is wrong to use any kind of independently running clock for testing timeouts. It would be better if this is completely under the control of the unit test.

Is there a way I can implement this without having to change too much in the library code, that can be added to the unit tests?

The library code with timeout is more or less structured as:

```
var startTime = TimeService.CurrentTime;
while (TimeService.CurrentTime < startTime + timeout)
{
    // do something
    Thread.Sleep(50); // or so
}
```

and it would be difficult to change this structure.

Comment: [nodatime](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/master/src/NodaTime.Test/DurationTest.Construction.cs) covers duration in some of it's test cases and it looks like some of them express the expected value in [int64](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/master/src/NodaTime.Test/DurationTest.Operators.cs) to avoid converting the datetime back.

Comment: As for the random failure of certain test cases based on the machines performance, one way of covering this is to re-run the test case multiple times or somehow identify failed test cases as opposed to errors in a test case.

Comment: @lloyd Yes, re-running could help reducing false negatives, but I'm not a big fan of  repeating tests until they finally succeed (might also hide real problems). Also it does not really allow me to further reduce the run time of the tests substantially.

Comment: MS took a different approach and eliminated their [flaky tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/devops-at-microsoft/eliminating-flaky-tests). [salesforce](https://engineering.salesforce.com/flaky-tests-and-how-to-avoid-them-25b84b756f60) has the concept of resource pools. If you could separate out these tests and execute them sequentially (assuming you are executing them in parallel) and ensure they release all resources and the end of execution.

Comment: @lloyd thank you for the interesting links! But I still have the hope that the tests can be made this more deterministic by replacing the free-running clock with something under control of the test script.